# Unable to match the encrypted payload string repsonse in PHP and JAVA

Tags: java, php, encryption, initialization-vector

I'm trying to encrypt the json data in `PHP` and `JAVA`. But unable to match the response of both.

Can we generate IV(Initialization Vector) value based on specific parameter?
In PHP, we have functions to do. I'm trying to encrypt the data using below function and passing `$iv` as one of the parameter.

```
$secretKey= 'BDGAJDL7AGSNPBST';
```

**PHP:**

```
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
                         (or)
$iv = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(static::INIT_VECTOR_LENGTH / 2));

// Encrypt input text
$encryptedPayload = openssl_encrypt($plainText,static::CIPHER,$secretKey,OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,$iv);
                         (or)
$encryptedPayload = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $secretKey, $plainText, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
```

The above PHP function is always returns different value. IV is meant to provide unique values every time.

I'm trying to match the return value of below JAVA code. Which is always returning same encrypted string.

**JAVA**

```
try{    
     Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
     SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes(UTF_8), "AES");   
     cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(encryptionKey.getBytes(UTF_8)));
     response = cipher.doFinal(convertPOJOtoJSON(user).getBytes(UTF_8));
}catch (Exception e) {
    //
}
return response;
```

Comment: Notice the Java code gets the IV from the `encryptionKey`... you don't do that in the php.

Comment: ... and shouldn't do it at all.  Deriving your IV from the encryption key is not a very intelligent thing to do.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Can you please suggest how can I achieve this in PHP ?

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark I felt it was may be because of random bytes generated by IV.

Answer (score 0):

You really should not have to "match" an IV.  The IV along with an HMAC should be appended to the cipher text.  Just as long as the PHP and the JS parse the IV and HMAC from cipher text string the same way you will be just fine.

An IV is really just a random string of a certain length that is used to seed/salt your encryption and is not dependent on a key.

A HMAC is a hash of the cipher text(that is dependent on the key) that is used to authenticate the cipher text before decrypting.  This HMAC is appended to the cipher text along with the IV.  Before decrypting you will hash the cipher text and compare it with the hash appended to the cipher text.  If they match then nothing has been tampered with.  If they don't match you should consider the data to be compromised.

I would recommend using the Libsodium library for your encryption needs.  It is now native for the latest version of PHP and you can also find it for JS.

[Libsodium - PHP](https://github.com/paragonie/pecl-libsodium-doc/tree/v1)

[Libsodium - JS](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium.js?files=1)

Here is a good doc to get you started.

[A good encryption/authentication read](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/using-encryption-and-authentication-correctly)

Comment: Thank you @Joseph_J,  I'm calling one service built-in java, which is expecting same encrypted string because they are generating Hmac using encrypted string and matching the Hmac from their end. When I decrypt the encrypted string of mine, I can see the plain text. And it's not JS, it is Java.

Comment: Oops, sorry about the JS/Java mix up, You can find Libsodium for Java too.  I am sorry.  I do not completely understand your question.  In your code I do not see where you are appending the IV or HMAC to the cipher text during the encryption.  I do not see where you are parsing the IV, or HMAC on decryption.  Please study the last link in my answer.  It shows you proper handling, you just have to adopt the logic with the crypto classes you choose to use... The process is the same.  Maybe update your question with a more pointed description of your problem.